# PetaPoco - Transaction isolation level on insert to DB

Tags: c#, database, orm, petapoco

Is there a way to set isolation level on Insert to DB using PetaPoco!

Transaction locks the database while its not completed, 
I know there are ways to edit the actual query's or SP's but is there a way to control isolation level via petapoco? It seems as there was an option in earlier version, but cant find anything in latest versions.

My current example code:

```
using (var scope = contextasync.getInstance().GetTransaction())
{
    try {
        object userId = context.Insert(user);
        example.UserId = user.Id;
        object affected2 = context.Insert(example); }catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //log the error

    }
scope.Complete();

}
```

Checked this, but it did not help:
[PetaPoco - setting transaction isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862748/petapoco-setting-transaction-isolation-level)

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of PetaPoco, you can now set the isolation level.

Using [fluent configuration](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Fluent-Configuration)

```
var db = config.Build()
         .UsingConnectionString("cs")
         .UsingProvider<SqlServerDatabaseProvider>()
         .UsingIsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.Chaos)
         .Create();

 db.IsolationLevel.ShouldBe(IsolationLevel.Chaos);
```

Or traditional constructor

```
var db = new Database("MyConnectionStringName") { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Chaos };
```